# Java fibonacci stack overflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    one();
    System.out.println();
}

public static void one() {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a number:");
  int i = sc.nextInt();

  for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
      System.out.println(fibonacci(j));
  }
}

public static int fibonacci(int num){
    if (num == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (num == 2 || num == 3){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fibonacci(num-1) + fibonacci(num-2);
    }
}
```

When I run this will get Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.StackOverflowError** but if I change one() to

```
public static void one() {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a number:");
  int i = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println(fibonacci(j));
}
```

I wont get error, even I just enter 1, could I ask why?

Comment: Your loop starts with `j=0` and what is the result of your `fibonacci` method?

Comment: Learn about `breakpoints`.  And then step through your code to see what's happening.  Very important skill for developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't handle the case of `num == 0`, so when you call `fibonacci(0)` the recursion never ends, leading to `StackOverflowError` when the stack is full.

You can solve it by changing the range of your loop

```
 for (int j=1; j<i; j++) {
     System.out.println(fibonacci(j));
 }
```

or by changing the stopping condition of your recursive method:

```
public static int fibonacci(int num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (num == 2 || num == 3){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fibonacci(num-1) + fibonacci(num-2);
    }
}
```

That said, it would be much more efficient to store the intermediate results of `fibonacci(i)`, and re-use them when calculating `fibonacci(n)` for `n > i` (instead of making unnecessary expansive recursive calls).

Answer (score 1):

In the for-Statement you start with 0. This is the first Input to fibonacci-Funktion. Try:

```
public static void one() {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
 int i = sc.nextInt();

 for (int j=1; j<i; j++) {
     System.out.println(fibonacci(j));
 }
```

Comment: @GökhanPolat Only if you ignore the fact that `fibonacci(0)` also exists.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed to handle the zero. Just try the following loop,

```
   for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
    System.out.println(fibonacci(j));
    }
```

Comment: The solution provided works when you consider the fact that Fibonacci starts from zero.

For example, when you input the total number as 4 
Output for the solution that I provided - 0 1 1 2 (Total number 4) 
But with the solution provided by Robert you will get the output - 0 1 1 (Total number 3)